# I can't read the status of the keyboard with pygame.get_pressed()

Tags: python, pygame

I'm experiencing a "simple" problem with pygame that is getting me totally nuts. Basically, when I try to read the status of the keyboard, all the values inside pygame.get_pressed() are zero. I've tried everything without any result. Here is my code, any idea about what am I doing wrong?

As an example, here is a small portion of code that should print "1" when I press the space bar:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()

o_canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 240))

while True:
    print pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not dismiss the events in the event queue, the window becomes unresponsive and input is not grabbed properly.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()

o_canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 240))

while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        pass
    # or pygame.event.clear()
    print pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution after so many headaches. Now I understand why everything was working fine while I used my temporary control code with pygame.event.get() and my final code with pygame.get_pressed()...  

I thought both systems where totally independent.